# windows 2003 server cpu utilization

Tags: cpu-usage

I have DELL Power Edge T410 server (Quad Core Dual Xeon 5500 Series with 16 GB Ram), installed Windows 2003 Server.
I write a code in C# to play with large amount of nos and after certain calculations the results are stored in a 6000 x 6000 matrix. Finally it write this matrix (36 Million entries) to a text file (172 MB).
When I run this program on my laptop, the CPU utilization goes to 100 % and it takes abput 40 hours to complete this task.
When I run this program on my server, the CPU utilization goes to just 10 % and it takes almost same 40 hours to complete this task.
Now my problem, is that obviously, the server should utilize more CPU , at least 70 % and should complete this task in shorter time, How can I achieve this goal ?

Comment: Sounds like programming problem to me.  Specifically, it almost sounds like you have a single-threaded process.  In any case, just to be sure, run perfmon, resmon, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the code to take advantage of the greater capabilities of the server, such as the additional cores.